# What action variable is needed for a Java servlet class?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have this reverse.html in the root /Reverse directory

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Assignment Servlets-2 - Reverse</h1>

    <form method='post' action='ReverseServlet'>
      Text: <input type='text' name='text' size='50'><br><br>
      <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the web.xml in the /WEB-INF directory

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
  <servlet> <servlet-name>ReverseServlet</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>ReverseServlet</servlet-class> </servlet> 

  <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>ReverseServlet</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/reverse</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is the ReverseServlet.java source which is compiled into a class file in the /classes directory

```
import java.io.* ;
import javax.servlet.http.* ;

public class ReverseServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) {
        String text = request.getParameter("text");

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println( new StringBuffer( text ).reverse().toString() );
            out.close();
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( "cannot get writer: " + e );
        }
    }
}
```

They are all in the proper directories, and I can load the reverse.html, but the action won't tie to the ReverseServlet class. I'm using Tomcat 7.0 and I've gotten a simple servlet to work, so I know it's installed correctly. It just won't go to the servlet code upon hitting submit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are sending request using **post** method and trying catch it using **get** method.

1 way:

try to channge `post` to `get` or remove method attribute from form:
    `<form method='get' action='/reverse'>`

OR

2 way:
implement doPost method in your ReverseServlet in order to catch request from post method:

```
public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ){...}
```

Comment: Oh sweet lord. It finally WORKED! I'm so used to the javac method of hunting down errors and java logic. Servlets are about 100 times harder to get used to it seems. Maybe because I've not delt with them before now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The form's action should be the servlet's URL, not its name:

```
<form method='post' action='/reverse'>
```

Comment: I tried to change it around to localhost:8080/Reverse/reverse.html, I added in the /Reverse/reverse to the action variable because /reverse did not work. And it's saying that "The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource." Am I just way off on the code here for a working servlet? This is only my second attempt at one.